# Swift and Objective-C interoperability

Tags: swift, objective-c, frameworks

I am working on a project in which we are migrating from iOS project to framework. I am facing issues with Objective-C and Swift interoperability.

I have one Swift class named `Profile`. It has been exposed to Objective-C.

```swift
import Foundation

@objc public class Profile: NSObject {
    @objc public var name : String?

    @objc public func getName() -> String{
        return "XYZ"
    }
}
```

When I am importing “ProductName-Swift.h” it is showing me an error in generated header for the module map like “@import ModuleMapPrivate not found”.

I wanted to know if there is any way in which I can import “Profile-Swift.h” instead of “ProductName-Swift.h”?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried by adding User Header search paths

Comment: Use SPM and forget about user header search paths

Comment: Not sure Profile-swift.h exists . May be you can try to add the swift header file in the prefix pch file